# Developing Light weight registry service for android app

Tags: java, android, uddi, rmiregistry

I want to develop a light weight registry service for android device similar to UDDI Concept.

An UDDI is heavy weight which find difficult to implement to resource constrain devices.

Does a AIDL supports UDDI Features like publish, subscribe and access control or do i need to use any other method to develop a light weight registry for android device.
An explanation or link to the topic might be help full

Comment: you want a registry for storing what kind of information? ever considered just accessing a UDDI registry from android? everything you've described sounds like a server side component that you would access from a mobile device

Comment: i need to publish a inbuilt android application services into the registry so that the requester can access this services remotely